# Consumer consuming different topic data

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

`Context:`
In our NodeJS app, we have setup 2 consumers having their respective topics eg: A1 & A2. These consumers start when the service is initialized. we have added the initialization method call in index.js.

`Issue:` I have noticed that A1 consumer is consuming data from A2 topic, Ideally it should consume only the data present in A1 topic.

I tried investing related to this but can't find this specific scenario.

`index.js`

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    logger.info(`Server started listening on port ${app.get('port')}.`);
    startReadingFromA1();
    startReadingFromA2();
});

initializeConsumer = async (
    logger: LogWrapper,
    clientId: string,
    topicName: string,
    callback: any,
    maxBytes: number = DEFAULT_KAFKA_CONSUMER_MAX_BYTES
) => {
    const country = topicName.split('-')[0];
    logger.info(`Initializing Consumer for clientId: ${clientId} and topicName: ${topicName}`);
    this.setClientId(clientId);
    let brokerList = this.getBrokerList();
    this.setBrokers(brokerList);
    this.setSasl(false);
    this.setSSL();
    this.setLogLevel(logLevel.ERROR);
    const kafkaConsumerObj = this.initialize();
    //group-<country>-<module>-<env>
    const groupId = `group-${topicName.toLowerCase()}-${process.env.NODE_ENV}`;
    if (!this.isConnected) {
        await this.connectToKafkaCluster(kafkaConsumerObj, groupId, maxBytes);
    }
    await this.subscribeConsumer(topicName);
    logger.info(`Connected Consumer Kafka cluster`);
    this.getMessage(logger, callback, country);
}


initialize = () => {
    return new Kafka({
        clientId: this.clientId,
        brokers: this.brokerList,
        sasl: this.sasl,
        ssl: this.ssl,
        logLevel: this.logLevel.ERROR,
        connectionTimeout: DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
        retry: {
            initialRetryTime: 100,
            retries: 3,
        },
    });
};

const startReadingFromA1 = async () => {
const logger = LogHelper.getLoggerWithoutReq();
try {
    logger.info(`Initializing the Kafka read from Topic`);
    const Consumer = KafkaConsumer.getInstance();
    const consumerId = nanoid();
    let countryInCaps = process.env.COUNTRY ? process.env.COUNTRY.toUpperCase() : null;
    await Consumer.initializeConsumer(logger, `CONS-${consumerId}`, `${countryInCaps}-ModuleA`, handleMessages);
    return true;
} catch (err) {
    logger.error(`Error in startReadingFromA1: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
}
}


const startReadingFromA2 = async () => {
const logger = LogHelper.getLoggerWithoutReq();
try {
    logger.info(`Initializing the Kafka read from Topic`);
    const Consumer = KafkaConsumer.getInstance();
    const consumerId = nanoid();
    let countryInCaps = process.env.COUNTRY ? process.env.COUNTRY.toUpperCase() : null;
    await Consumer.initializeConsumer(logger, `CONS-${consumerId}`, `${countryInCaps}-ModuleB`, handleFailedMessages);
    return true;
} catch (err) {
    logger.error(`Error in startReadingFromA2: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add the code that initializes the consumers in the question?

Comment: You're still missing the actual `initializeConsumer` method call.

Comment: No, `startReadingFromA1` and `startReadingFromA2` are still not shown.

Comment: You should also add output from `kafka-consumer-groups --describe --group 'group-<country>-<module>-<env>'` for each group

Comment: both the consumer have different group-Id, which I have already checked.

Comment: Okay, but we don't know that. Can you please edit the post to include the details that were asked for? Just upload your whole code at this point, because we still don't have a [mcve] with `startReadingFromA2()` not shown or explanation what is `KafkaConsumer` vs `Consumer`. Seems to me like `KafkaConsumer.getInstance()` returns a singleton and so you're subscribing one consumer to multiple topics, not "2 consumers" as you describe. More specifically, both have the same clientId. Perhaps you should append Country/topic name to clientId config?

Comment: In client-Id, I am sending nano-id so i don't think so here there should be any issue

Comment: `returns a singleton` - correct, So i should have new consumer here right ?

Comment: Issue was with same consumer reading multiple topics.